# Why would a method have const and non const arguments for the same variable?

Tags: c++, function, methods, constants

I have seen a code which accepts first arg as const and another as modifiable. 
Is it good practice to pass the same variable for both the arguments during the implementation?

I could not understand the motive of the developer who uses the method in such a crude way. Is this something uncommon?

```
void manipulate(const string& a, string& b)
{
  if (a.length() > 0 )
    b.append("_ok");
}

int main()
{
  string a("Hello");
  manipulate(a, a);

}
```

I want to understand whether using such a crude way of implementation a correct approach or not.

Comment: What's crude about it?

Comment: It's not particularly common but also not inherently problematic. It may well be the clearest way to do things, that really depends on the problem being solved.

Comment: Imagination time: Lets say you had a bunch of strings that you wanted to examine for illegal characters, and you want the result of every examination to be written to a common log. You could then make a function like the one above, and pass the string to be inspected as const, and the log as non-const. But then what if you needed to inspect the log for illegal characters? Well, you might just pass the log itself as both arguments to the function you already have.

Comment: _@RonakSHAH_ This question looks like that ypu have simplified the real use case of what you found too much. Can you please post what the original code was, and where you found it? The function itself cannot know what is passed as paremeter, and if the parameters refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

A const reference only means: You cannot modify the object via the reference.

It does not mean: The instance cannot be modified through other means.

This is perfectly legal:

```
void foo(const std::string& a, std::string& b) {
     b = a + "foo";
}

int main() {
    std::string x { "hello world"};
    foo(x, x);
}
```

In general methods should be written without hidden constraints, eg it should be possible to pass the same parameter for two different arguments (as above). Moreover, this is not in contrast to const-correctness. To the contrary, the example above is a good example for const-correctness helping to avoid mistakes. Eg you cannot call it as

```
const std::string y{"hello const"};
foo(y, y);  // error
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to understand whether using such a crude way of implementation a correct approach or not.

There's nothing *crude* or wrong in the implementation.

The intend is pretty clear:

```
 b.append("_ok");
```

changes the value of `b`, thus it needs to be passed as non `const` reference parameter.

---

A more common way to write such function would be

```
string& manipulate(string& a)
{
  if (a.length() > 0 )
    a.append("_ok");
  return a;
}
```

though.

---

Why the particular implementation of the function has specified a const and a non const reference parameter can't be answered without seeing a specific use case.
The function itself cannot know that the references point at the same variable.

Comment: The OP's point is that by passing the same variable as both const *and* non-const violates const correct-ness.

Comment: @suspectus I can't see any violaiton of const correctness.

Comment: I dont get the downvote. Given that the quesiton isnt quite clear (it misses to explain what is supposed to be "crude" about the method) answers necessarily have to do some guessing

Comment: You are correct in that technically the compiler doesn't see any violation. The point is that b is a reference to a. So the code changes a variable passed as a non-const reference but also passed as a const reference. I would say the code lacks clarity because it wangles a change to a variable which is passed as const parameter.

Comment: @suspectus That's why I added an example how this would be commonly be implemented.

Comment: @suspectus Modifiying variables while someone holds a const reference isnt something you can avoid, if you assume a variable cannot change just because you have a const reference to it, then you better change that false assumption ;)

Comment: I would say the code *is* crude.

Answer (score 2):

If the method `void manipulate(const string& a, string& b)` should only be called with same arguments, changing signature to `void manipulate(string&)` would make sense.

If not it is valid.

We should be care in implementation with this kind of aliasing to behave correctly when identical parameter is given. Here once `b` is modified, `a` is too.

Comment: There might be many reasons why the function is implemented as is. Required signatures for callbacks, whatever.